# SQLAlchemy Text Parameter Binding gives '?'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

I have this:

```
q = text('select top 10 * from :x')

conn.execute(q, x="mytable")
```

which fails returning:

> ```
> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Must declare the table variable "@P1". (1087) (SQLExecDirectW)')
> [SQL: select top 10 * from ?]
> [parameters: ('mytable',)]
> ```

Running `q = test('select top 10 * from mytable')` works however.

I'm at a lost as I've tried `bindparams`.

Comment: You can't use bind parameters for anything other than **data**. The point of bind parameters is to prevent data from being interpreted as database syntax (objects, `FROM`, `AS`, etc.).

Comment: I get the same error if I do this:
`q = text('select top :num * from mytable')`

`conn.execute(q, num=10)`

Answer (score 1):

Martijin's comment is correct. The bind parameters only work for data.

```
q = text('select top 10 * from :x')

conn.execute(q, x="mytable")
```

is invalid.

But this,

```
q = text('select :x from mytable')

conn.execute(q, x="thing1")
```

works.